# How can I concat month column and year column to yearmonth column

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

I have an SQL table with columns (month, year, and yearmonth)

```
Month    year    
 5       2020
 6       2020
 11      2020
```

I want to insert yearmonth column values in this format

```
yearmonth
   202005
   202006
   202011
```

I've tried couple of Datetime functions, but it didn't work.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Have you considered using the `concat()` function to, well, concat things?

Comment: Yes I tried contat(). But its adding up the values. I'm not getting in YYYYMM format. @mustaccio

Answer (score 4):

I think that it is simpler to use string functions:

```
select t.*, concat(year, lpad(month, 2, '0')) as yearmonth
from mytable t
```

`lpad()` adds the "missing" `0` to the month part if needed, which you can then concatenate with the year.

On the other hand, if you want a numeric result, arithmetics is the way to go:

```
select t.*, year * 100 + month as yearmonth
from mytable t
```

Comment: It worked pretty well. Didn't about lpad before. I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string, I might use:

```
select cast(year * 100 + month as char)
```